# How to repair Web Setup Wizard redirecting to 404 Not Found in Magento CE 2.2.5/2.2.6?

Tags: http-status-code-404, upgrade, magento2

This is a very critical issue.

I recently upgraded from Magento CE 2.2.5 to CE 2.2.6 using the Web Setup Wizard.

The upgrade went fine and the site is working.

When I try to access Web Setup Wizard in 2.2.6, I get a 404 Not Found response.

[image: 404 Not Found]

What I already tried:

- I removed all files and contents from `/var/`
- I cleaned Magento cache
- I tried accessing the setup from a different browser
- Tried solutions such as accessing through http and https and activated/deactivated `HTTP Strict Transport Security`
- The Document Root points to `/path/to/magento/` and not `/path/to/magento/pub/`

Please note that I have a test instance on a different machine, this one was upgraded to 2.2.6 using **composer**. On this instance, `/setup/` is working fine.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Anyone having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have tried almost everything. 
You can also try to check the access to the setup folder in the root folder of Magento, and check the rules in the .htaccess file there. Hope it will help you.